# Repeat range dynamically

Tags: google-sheets

**Hoping for a nudge in the right direction.**

Summary:
I work a Nursery and have been teaching myself Google Spreadsheets to help with organization.  I've come along way but find myself stuck on this function I'm trying to do, and what would be useful throughout my project.

There are multi areas that have different feeding/watering schedules. What I'm trying to achieve is to be able to change the schedule and have it repeat down column B for all the dates in column A.

Here is a example sheet that I set up.  This is a small piece of a much bigger project that I have been working on for the past 6 months.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Mj5X-Xhw6_VCur2hdqeRk1HWvqHSWLg4oCndLubsyAU/edit?usp=sharing

Note: Sometimes, for example, in Area 1, the number of cells to repeat will be 5, and other time it will be 4, depending on the time of year and weather.  No matter the number of cells to repeat, the result I am going for is that it is repeated down column B if there is a date in column A

I hope I've explained this correctly.
Thanks in advance for any help I receive.

Comment: Do you want unique values from `B2:B2` for all cells that have value in column A?

Comment: For example: if there is a value in A2:A8, repeat it in A9:A

Comment: I ment f there is a value in B2:B8

Comment: Give a try on `=FLATTEN(SPLIT(REPT(JOIN("|",B2:B8)&"|",ROUNDDOWN(COUNTA(A9:A)/COUNTA(B2:B8),0)),"|"))`.

Comment: Make sure to add input and expected output as **text table** (NOT as IMAGE) to the question. [Click here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) to create a table easily. Adding such tables greatly increases your chances of getting a elegant answer, as **it is easier to copy/paste**. If you share spreadsheets, your question maybe closed, as questions here must be [self contained](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455). Your table should be a [mre].[Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), if you share Google files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate the remainder after dividing the row in A9:A by the number of items in the list in B2:B8 (5 in your example) using Row and Mod. Then use Vlookup to find this value in the corresponding row in B2:B8

```
=ArrayFormula(if(A9:A="",,vlookup(mod(row(A9:A)-row(A9),counta(B2:B8)),{row(B2:B8)-row(B2),B2:B8},2)))
```

then copy the formula across to the other columns.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=INDEX(IF(A9:A="",,LAMBDA(x, y, REDUCE(x, SEQUENCE(y), LAMBDA(a, b, IF(b, {a; x}))))
 (B2:INDEX(B:B, MAX((B1:B8<>"")*ROW(B1:B8))), COUNTA(A9:A)/COUNTA(B2:B8))))
```

[image]